# How do you set PassengerFriendlyErrorPages in .htaccess?

Tags: centos, apache2, phusion-passenger

I have a working server setup with Apache running with Phusion Passenger. Because the friendly error page turned off by default (good for production apps), it's hard to spot the error when it's happen.

I want to enable [PassengerFriendlyErrorPages](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengerfriendlyerrorpages) specific for some sites, using `.htaccess`:

```
PassengerFriendlyErrorPages on
```

But then Apache results in 500 error (Edit: still same error):

```
/home/area51/public_html/public/.htaccess: PassengerFriendlyErrorPages not allowed here
```

Is there something I miss? (note the documentation says the context can be in .htaccess so it made me confused)

PS: `httpd.conf` works, though it's not my option here.

EDIT: My apache config, as I don't know why it still not working. (Yes I'm aware about `systemctl restart httpd`)

I put the `.htaccess` in `/home/area51/public_html/public`

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.1.6:80>
SuexecUserGroup "#1083" "#1083"
ServerName area51.dom.my.id
ServerAlias www.area51.dom.my.id
DocumentRoot /home/area51/public_html/public
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/area51.dom.my.id_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/area51.dom.my.id_access_log combined
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
<Directory /home/area51/public_html/public>
RewriteEngine On
allow from all
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php7.2
<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler proxy:fcgi://localhost:8014
</FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I just noticed that you seem to be using Virtualmin. That is probably part or all of the problem here, and anyway, we consider such systems [unsupportable](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/8094/126632) here.

Comment: It's weird that such system can introduce this problem (like, this should be specific for apache). But I understand anyway. Thanks, I will move to their forums instead in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The `<Directory>` containing the `.htaccess` file must itself allow this, with [`AllowOverride Options`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride).

Comment: Is `AllowOverride All` (without Options) enough? I've been trying different configurations and restarting httpd couple of times with no luck.

Comment: Yes, `All` should also be sufficient.

Comment: I did it. Unfornatunely it still doesn't work. Must be something else. I have edited my question to add the httpd.conf part that relevant.

Comment: @willnode You don't have a `<Directory>` that matches the directory your `.htaccess` is in. Check the path carefully.

Comment: Sorry, I did move the .htacess to `/home/area51/public_html/public/.htaccess`. Still not working. The app is in `/home/area51/public_html/app.js` if that's relevant.

Comment: @willnode You also need to remove the old Apache 2.2 directive `allow from all`.

Comment: I did it. Still the same. Now here's some interesting pattern, i put `Options +Indexes` before the passenger line in .htaccess, just for checking. turns out that options indexes passes (still err to passenger). Then I remove `AllowOverride All` in httpd.conf, now that options is not allowed. even though I set the default directory allowoverride to all.

Comment: So this all just made me more confused. If AllowOverride All didn't work, then it must be my server setup that goes wrong. I don't know, I might just stick to put them to httpd.conf right now. Thanks for your help anyway.